# Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 arguments, 1 given

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to build a site where I can upload multiple images with php and mysql but I am getting below error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 arguments, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\RENT\component\test-folder\upload.php:37 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\RENT\component\test-folder\upload.php(37): mysqli_stmt->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\RENT\component\test-folder\upload.php on line 37

```
#inserting image name into database
$sql = "INSERT INTO image_upload (image_name) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$new_img_name]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using PHP 8.0. This version didn't allow passing an array in the `execute()` method; it's only available as of PHP 8.1. You must bind the parameters using the `bind_param()` method.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO image_upload (image_name) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $new_img_name); // one s for each parameter
$stmt->execute();
```

You should also consider using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of mysqli which would make your life easier. With PDO you could always pass an array to `execute()`.